# how to match and replace listA column1 value to ListB column2 value that matches with ListB column1 same like we do in vlookup

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 list (header and dataValue). I want to match and replace my data value column 1 to header file column 1 for value that match with dataValue columnn 1 with header value column 2

Header file

```
TotalLoad,M0001001
HoisePosition,X011_0001
TotalLoad1,X011_0004
TotalLoad2,X030_0008
HoisePosition2,X031_0002
GearTemprature,X032_0003
OilLevel,X033_0004
OilTemprature,X034_0005
```

Data Value

```
M0001001,50
X011_0001,100
X011_0004,45
X030_0008,35
X030_0002,80
X030_0003,100
X030_0004,200
X030_0005,60
```

python

```
Hfile=open("header.csv",'r')
DValuef=open("DataValue.csv",'r')
hf=Hfile.readlines()
dv=DValuef.readlines()
Hfile.close()
DValuef.close()

dictA={}
dictB={}
value1=[]
value2=[]

for x in hf:
    myList1=x.strip().split(',')
    dictA={myList1[0]:myList1[1]}
    value1.append(dictA)

for y in dv:
    myList2=y.strip().split(',')
    dictB={'Vname':myList2[0],'V_Value':myList2[1]}
    print(dictB)
```

Expected result

```
{'Vname': 'TotalLoad', 'V_Value': '50'}
{'Vname': 'HoisePosition', 'V_Value': '100'}
{'Vname': 'TotalLoad1', 'V_Value': '45'}
{'Vname': 'TotalLoad2', 'V_Value': '35'}
{'Vname': 'HoisePosition2', 'V_Value': '80'}
{'Vname': 'GearTemprature', 'V_Value': '100'}
{'Vname': 'OilLevel', 'V_Value': '200'}
{'Vname': 'OilTemprature', 'V_Value': '60'}
```

Actual result

```
{'Vname': 'M0001001', 'V_Value': '50'}
{'Vname': 'X011_0001', 'V_Value': '100'}
{'Vname': 'X011_0004', 'V_Value': '45'}
{'Vname': 'X030_0008', 'V_Value': '35'}
{'Vname': 'X030_0002', 'V_Value': '80'}
{'Vname': 'X030_0003', 'V_Value': '100'}
{'Vname': 'X030_0004', 'V_Value': '200'}
{'Vname': 'X030_0005', 'V_Value': '60'}
```

Comment: why don't you make a dictionary like  {'TotalLoad' : '50', 'HoisePosition' : '100', 'TotalLoad1' : '45', 'TotalLoad2', : '35'}

Comment: The list is somewhere around 400 and i only able to pass parameter with address "x030..." to read the value. so when come to the result i want to replace the address with my own declaration name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for x in hf:
    myList1=x.strip().split(',')
    dictA[myList1[1]] = myList1[0]

for y in dv:
    myList2=y.strip().split(',')
    dictB={'Vname':dictA[myList2[0]],'V_Value':myList2[1]}
    print(dictB)
```

this should give u what u need.. but i don't why you need to arrange the data like this

Comment: yes, this is wrong, you dont have access to the myList1 from the 2nd loop

Comment: this make sense, you are using the last value saved in the myList1.

Comment: why don't you try running the answer i gave you

Comment: Sorry it's works. thanks for your help. this is what i really excepted.

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in hf:
    myList1=x.strip().split(',')
    dictA[myList1[1]] = myList1[0]

for y in dv:
    myList2=y.strip().split(',')
    dictB[dictA[myList2[0]] : myList2[1]]
print(dictB)
```

this is a better format

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like below using list comprehension

```py
header_file = '''TotalLoad,M0001001
HoisePosition,X011_0001
TotalLoad1,X011_0004
TotalLoad2,X030_0008
HoisePosition2,X031_0002
GearTemprature,X032_0003
OilLevel,X033_0004
OilTemprature,X034_0005'''

value_file = '''M0001001,50
X011_0001,100
X011_0004,45
X030_0008,35
X030_0002,80
X030_0003,100
X030_0004,200
X030_0005,60'''

hf = [line for line in header_file.split("\n")]
dv = [line for line in value_file.split("\n") ]

header_dict = {key: value for value, key in [line.split(",") for line in hf] }
value_dict = [{"Vname": header_dict.get(key), "V_value": value} for key, value in [line.split(",") for line in dv] ]

print(value_dict)
```

Comment: Hi Dev, looks good. but if the value address is not in the list it returning none. i actually wants exception if the list is not there.

Comment: for that you can use ```header_dict[key]``` instead of ```header_dict.get(key)```